# What tools are there to help me draw my symbol?

Tags: worldbuilding-resources

I'm designing an esoteric symbol to use in a story.

I have zero experience with this but can use drawing/CAD softwares. Where can I find some resources on how to design a symbol?

I guess a good list of existing ones with references to meanings, associated concepts and cultures would also help.

I'm talking about a symbol specifically, not a logo or trademark etc.

Comment: Are you looking for graphical design resources?

Comment: @L.Dutch not sure what you mean but I guess they could help as well

Comment: You are using the word "[symbol](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/symbol#English)" in a very non-standard way, so readers cannot guess the intended meaning. For example, a frakking logo *is* a symbol - it symbolizes the organization to which it belongs. A trademark is any kind of mark (symbolic or not) which identifies a manufacturer. In general, a symbol is any character, glyph, object or word which represents an idea, concept or object in a conventional way. For example, the character `$` is a symbol for "dollar"; [Marianne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marianne) is a symbol of France; ...

Comment: @AlexP Fair enough. The Coca Cola logo is a symbol for the company but only when draw with a certain shape (and maybe color), while the pentagram is a symbol for Satan no matter how you write it, how do you call the second one? a glyph? a grapheme?

Comment: The pentagram is not normally a symbol for Satan, bad Hollywood movies excepted; its symbolic uses are more frequently associated with the five phylosophical elements or other groups of five (wounds of Christ, virtues, joys of Mary etc.) -- now you see the problem with symbols: there no official and unvarying list of meanings. The specific shape and color of a logo are enforced to ensure uniformity (and thus memorability), not because they are legally required: you cannot use the Coca-Cola logo slanted to the left and colored blue and hope that the usage is non-infringing.

Comment: And to be helpful: the general field of study of symbols and meanings is called [semiotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics). Start with the Wikipedia article and follow the links. Occasionally, you may find online copies of famous books, such as [*Man and His Symbols*](https://monoskop.org/images/9/97/Von_Franz_Luise_Marie_Jung_Gustav_Carl_Man_and_His_Symbols_1988.pdf), Carl Jung, ed., 1964.

Comment: @AlexP While your first comment contained constructive criticism, your second one is not helpful at all, you're just complaining that definitions vary and are not legally binding. I'm not interested in either definitions nor legality, just in resources to develop a symbol; the type I believe is decently described by the combination of my answer and comment.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're looking for with this question. If you're looking for software to help draw symbols, there's graphical editors like Paint and Photoshop. Are you looking for a guide on the background of certain symbols, how they came to be like they are and what the original intent for the design was?

Comment: I think it would be a mistake to use any tools to develop a symbol which would not be normally available in your target world culture. For example, there are no wiggly runes (or wiggly cuneiform characters, for much the same reason).

Comment: I would recommend using vector based program if you want to create your symbols. I just find them more intuitive for that purpose. The 2 I know are Inkscape (free) and Adobe illustrator (not free) but there are others as well. I am not sure if this is what you are looking, but if you are interested in heraldry/vexillology and don't want to design all the symbols yourself, there a ton of usually free symbols here: http://all-silhouettes.com/

Comment: Pencil, paper, heraldry, celtic knots, have fun!